# Container not writing data to physical disk file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Python Code:

```
import datetime,os
data = ""
with open("D://PythonService//Test.txt", "w") as outFile:
    outFile.write(data + "Service started at - {}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    outFile.close()
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD ["python", "WriteData.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    newfoldercopy:
        image: newfoldercopy
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - D:/PythonService:/var/lib/data/
```

I am trying to mount my physical file system path to the container.
But the container is not writing data on a physical file, the container is writing data on a container virtual file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
with open("D://PythonService//Test.txt", "w") as outFile:
```

to:

```
with open("/var/lib/data/Test.txt", "w") as outFile:
```

because of this line in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
        volumes:
          - D:/PythonService:/var/lib/data/
```

Also instead of:

```
outFile.write(data + "Service started at - {}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

You can use `f-string`:

```
outFile.write(f'{data} Service started at - {datetime.datetime.now()}\n')
```

which makes your code more readable.

Also as I understood, using `with open()` closes your file automatically, so you can change your Python code from:

```
with open("D://PythonService//Test.txt", "w") as outFile:
    outFile.write(data + "Service started at - {}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    outFile.close()
```

to:

```
with open("/var/lib/data/Test.txt", "w") as outFile:
    outFile.write(f'{data} Service started at - {datetime.datetime.now()}\n')
```

Comment: Getting exception `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/data/Test.txt'`

Comment: Check if `Test.txt` exists in `D:/PythonService/`

Comment: still writing data on container virtual file. Not writing data on the physical text file.

Comment: I think that's because of `COPY . /app` in your `Dockerfile`. Please comment this line by adding `#` and build image again to check it.

Comment: Getting exception `python: can't open file 'WriteData.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Container is not loading file from `D:/PythonService` to `/var/lib/data/`. Instead container is creating file in `/var/lib/data/`.

Comment: First, comment the `COPY . /app` line. Then run `docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d`.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand

`D:/PythonService` - local path

`/var/lib/data/`  - path inside container

In Python code you should use container path (/var/lib/data/) not local path (D:/PythonService)

Comment: still writing data on container virtual file. Not writing data on the physical text file

Comment: on what path the file is created in container ?

And one test you could do. If you load a file to `D:/PythonService` directory you should see it in `/var/lib/data/` in container. Am I correct ?

Comment: Container is not loading file from `D:/PythonService` to `/var/lib/data/`. Instead container is creating file in `/var/lib/data/`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like `with open("/var/lib/data/Test.txt", "w") as outFile:`

all files written at `/var/lib/data` folder inside the container will be available to `D:/PythonService`

```
volumes:
  - <host directory>:<container directory>
```

Comment: still writing data on container virtual file. Not writing data on physical text file